# PHP and IIS7--> I updated the Environment %PATH% but PHP's Path not updating, even after cycling IIS

Tags: php, windows, batch-file, iis

I've got a batch file rigged up to do Mysql backups on two different servers, both running IIS7, both with their "Path" environment variables now including the path to MySQL's bin subdirectory (path is the same on both systems).

On one system, I'm having no problems.  On the other, the batch file keeps giving:
'mysqldump' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program, or batch file.

I dropped to DOS.  The DOS window "knew" where mysqldump was, just fine.  So, scratching my head, I went into IIS Manager and checked PHP. I used phpinfo() to look at the Path settings.   They are NOT showing my addition of the mysql bin directory.   So, I cycled the application pool. the sever (in the "tree" right above the app pool)... no change.

I really don't want to reboot the server if I don't have to, as it's a production server with people using it right now.

But I'm not sure what I need to do to get PHP to "take" that System Environment Variable / Path update.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set **`LoadUserProfile`** to `True` in the Application Pool that runs the PHP script.

Comment: Well, that sort of worked.  I actually editted the Environment Variables again, removing an unrelated one that I thought didn't belong.    And then, a few minutes later, I went back and found this page and tried what you recommended again.  ( I actually tried it yesterday... no change.)

Anyways, after doing that today, now I see my edit from YESTERDAY has been applied.  But that variable I removed a few minutes ago is still there.  Strange.

Answer (score 1):

i just found the answer here: https://serverfault.com/a/193614/388136

basically, iis loads the environment variables on startup and never refreshes them, so if you've made changes you have to restart the service itself. the optimal way to do that is running **iisreset** from the command line

Comment: After two days trying everything and restarting my IIS from the GUI I saw this suggestion!! iisreset saved my life!!!! @neogeek thank you so much!

Comment: glad to have helped someone :)

Answer (score 0):

Something iis reset doesn't work or load profile true is on default.
Most of the cases the path variable is not updating because php loads the path variables on its initial runtime. Something shutdown/ restarts fixes it but the optimal solution is:

- Open task manager
- Close all the php executables like `php.exe` and `php-cli`.
- Go to your iis php directory and click on php.exe and php-cli or you can restart your computer this will open them again with the latest configs.